# Insert element into private map from outside of the class

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, typedef

I got a map in header file as

```
    public:
    typedef map<string, int> mymap;

    private:
          mymap m;
```

in main.cpp, I would like to insert values into "m" which is a synonym to the map. How can I insert values? like

```
    m.insert(...);
```

Comment: Show your full class.

Comment: declare `m` as public, like ...`public: mymap m;` then you can insert values in it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert them directly, because `m` is a private member. You only have access to the public members from outside of the class (unless `main()` is a friend of the class, which is unlikely).

Possible solutions include adding (or using existing) public methods that will do the insertion for you:

```
public:
    void insert(std::pair<string, int> const &);
    void insert(string const &, int);
```

Or making the map public (probably a bad idea):

```
public:
    mymap m;
```

Or adding your `main()` function as a friend of the class (almost certainly a bad idea):

```
friend int main();
// Or, if your main() accepts the standard argc/argv parameters:
friend int main(int argc, char **argv);
```